# How to make a child box with height 100% respect other childs height?

Tags: html, css

Given the following snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/8wy1mku2/

```css
.black {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}

.grey {
  width: 180px;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
}

.red {
  width: 160px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  width: 140px;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="black">
  <div class="grey">
    <div class="red">red</div>
    <div class="blue">blue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the blue child with height 100% respect the space of the red child?

I want the blue box to automatically resize to be of size 100% minus the size of the red box.

Please help!

Comment: didnt find a way to save the snippet

Comment: You'll see the button "Save & insert into post"? Click on it in order to add the snippet as text

Comment: provides a good overview: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use flex on the grey box, then you can use flex grow on the blue box:

```css
.black {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}

.grey {
  width: 180px;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.red {
  width: 160px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  width: 140px;
  background: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="black">
  <div class="grey">
    <div class="red">red</div>
    <div class="blue">blue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yep! like that. For some reason I had to change reds height to min-height:20px, because it got reduced to 18px. Why? Is it possible to do that in the definition of grey?

Comment: flex calculates height based on content - you can use min height to make sure it has a minimum of 20px or try `flex-basis: 20px`

Comment: right: all your answers helped me figuring out more about that. A flex-shrink: 0 also hinders shrinking...

Comment: I am now using a combination of this flex setting and display: grid with grid-row-template: auto 1fr

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `calc` function. Like this:

**Syntax**

```css
height: calc(100% - heightOfTheRedBox);
```

```css
.black {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}

.grey {
  width: 180px;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
}

.red {
  width: 160px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  width: 140px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="black">
  <div class="grey">
    <div class="red">red</div>
    <div class="blue">blue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what else can you think of? Why doesn't the blue box know the available height itself?

Comment: @an.dr.eas.k There are always many ways to achieve a single thing in CSS. You can use FlexBox, Grid, You can even use JavaScript, display table, hardcoded value, etc...